# How do I change the render @events output based on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

On one view I have `render @events` which uses `_event.html.erb` to make the output. I want to use `render @events` on another area (homepage) but I want it to render the page slightly differently. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least this:

- use css which you can use to position elements, hide others, colors etc
- render different partials in each template

For the first option (I'll use haml and I'll make it simple):

```
# events.html.haml
.index= render @events

# homepage.html.haml
.events= render @events

# your css
.index  { color: red; }
.events { color: blue; }
```

Something simpler, which I believe is one of @iain suggestions:

```
# action template
= render partial: '/events/event1', collection: @events

# _event1.html.haml
.name #{event1.name}
```

This way you can *cleanly* make as many different partials as you like, with a little repetition on the render call. I agree that you should avoid if statement in views if possible.

I strongly suggest to refer to the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) as they're very clear and easy to read.

Hash here are Ruby 1.9 style, if you're with Ruby 1.8 replace something like `collection: @events` with something like `:collection => @events`

Hope this helps, sorry for drastic edit of my answer.

Comment: I am very new to rails so trying to figure out how to even explain what I want to do.

If I do render @events in two places, how do I make them call different partials? I want them to be a little different. On the homepage, I don't want render events to show certain information but on the events list page, I want all the information to be shown.

Comment: [and just in case you don't know haml](http://haml-lang.com), `<%= foo %>` in erb is converted to `= foo` in haml

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how different they are, you could use a presenter, like demonstrated in the [latest Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper).

If the difference is structural, just make two partials. A small amount of duplication in your views is totally acceptable and probably preferable to placing logic in your views.
Try to resist the urge to create if statements in your views.

Comment: exactly, the latest screencast was very very interesting! - both valid alternatives

Comment: @iain If I make two partials, how does rails know which one to use when I call render events?